# Using std::optional instead of own structure

Tags: c++, c++17

I need to use nullable type.

I found `std::optional` which perfectly meets my expectations.

But this feature is available from C++ 17, experimental branch from C++ 14. It means the compiler (different computer) has to be updated.

It is just allocated space for data and bool which indicates if variable exists or not.

Why should I use this feature instead of own structure?

Are there some benefits for using `std::optional`?

Thanks!

Comment: *Why should I use this feature instead of own structure?* Why write code you don't have to?

Comment: There is the boost version also, available before C++17.

Comment: @NathanOliver Because of people who don't have updated their compiler.

Comment: @Jarod42 Is Boost version standardized? I'd just like to use std.

Comment: I have a simliar issue regarding some other C++17 features and use the boost alternative for all.

Comment: boost is not std. I meant, if you cannot use `std`, as it seems you don't have access to C++17 contrary to tag might suggest, there are available implementations such as boost, which is a popular library (inspiriting std). and migrating afterward from boost to std is generally easy.

Comment: It is a weird question to me, dont you want to use c++17 and looking for alternatives ? Or something else ?

Comment: @JohnDoe: `std::optional` is derived from `boost::optional`, and in turn `boost::optional` will likely remain compatible with `std::optional`. That means you can write `using boost::optional` at the top of your file, and when you move to C++17 you can change just that single line. That is no coincidence, that's intentional.

Comment: I am just looking for benefits of std::optional instead of using own structure.

Comment: The benefits are that you get extensively tested, working, efficient code written by experts, and precisely documented, which plays well with other parts of the standard library and third-party libraries. And all of this for zero effort.

Comment: You should show the particular problem you are trying to solve. Otherwise this can be extremely opinion based. That said, if you can use std::optional and it perfectly meets your expectations, than just use it. You can implement your own std::find as well, but why would you?

Answer (score 5):

After realizing your point on the question, i want to answer with a quote.

> P.13: Use support libraries as appropriate.
>
> **Reason** Using a
>   well-designed, well-documented, and well-supported library saves time
>   and effort; its quality and documentation are likely to be greater
>   than what you could do if the majority of your time must be spent on
>   an implementation. The cost (time, effort, money, etc.) of a library
>   can be shared over many users. A widely used library is more likely to
>   be kept up-to-date and ported to new systems than an individual
>   application. Knowledge of a widely-used library can save time on
>   other/future projects. So, if a suitable library exists for your
>   application domain, use it.

from [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#p13-use-support-libraries-as-appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

In the end of the day, you are stuck with a dilemma. You have a standardized, well-supported feature, which is not available in your toolset. The toolset can be upgraded, but it's a hassle for different reasons.

At the same time, you have a homebrew solution, which is not standard, likely lacks features (since you were tailoring your homebrew to your particular use case and likely wouldn't spend efforts on supporting the use case you don't need), could have bugs in corner cases, but is immediately available. What to do, to upgrade or not to upgrade?

There is no answer (otherwise, there would be no dilemma), but what people tend to do in this case is

- Make sure their solution at least has the same interface as a standard one
- Put the solution into designated namespace (i.e. std_hack, future_std, etc)
- Once they naturally upgrade to the toolset with standard solution, they remove their homebrew from designated namespace, replace designated namespace with `std` on all invocations and have a drop-in standard replacement at very minimal costs.

Answer (score 1):

> But this feature is available from C++ 17, experimental branch from C++ 14. It means the compiler (different computer) has to be updated.

Firstly, updating your compiler should not, ideally, be a big deal.

If it *is* a big deal, the best thing to do is improve your processes until it is no longer a big deal.

If you really can't do it (and your project is going to be frozen in time for ever) just use the Boost version of the same thing. Pretty much everything added via tr1 or experimental was iterated on in Boost first, anyway.

Writing your own version of something with two existing (good, documented, well-tested) implementations you could use instead, should definitely be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there some benefits for using std::optional?

To my knowledge the purpose of `std::optional` and one main difference to alternatives is to have the value on the stack (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)):

> If an optional contains a value, the value is guaranteed to be allocated as part of the optional object footprint, i.e. **no dynamic memory allocation ever takes place**. Thus, an optional object models an object, not a pointer, even though operator*() and operator->() are defined.

Depending on your situation, this might be desirable or not. For an object to be present or not, a smart pointer might be sufficient, but then you have to use dynamic memory allocations.

Comment: Could you give me better explanation, please? I don't get the second part of your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnDoe not sure what you dont understand. Consider that the most simplistic "optional" is a pointer to a dynamically allocated object, it can point to something or be a nullptr. This can be decorated with a nice interface, or you can use a smart pointer. But then you must dynamically allocate the object, which sometimes is not what you want, then you can use `std::optional`